# Парсинг, как указать определённое имя класса для поиска

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Всем привет, заранее спасибо за помошь. На сайте имеются два дива на одном уровне

`<div class='results-holder results-all'>`

`<div class='results-holder'>`

Информация нужна только со второго, использую bs4

```
table = soup.find('div', class_='results-holder')
```

Соответственно выводит первый див, можно ли указать поиск строго по заданному имени классу?

Comment: `find_all(...)[1]` ?

Comment: Не хотелось б использовать индекс, так как иногда может отсутствовать  первый див, поэтому хотел найти этот элемент по классу.

Comment: Ведь можно удалить див и вложенные теги?